# Application expiration using NSTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimeinterval

How would I set this method to display the alert panel 30 days from the initial launch of the application?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib

{

    NSDate * today = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval expiry = ();


    if ([today timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > expiry){
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Trial period has ended", @"Please Register", nil, nil, nil);
        NSLog(@"expired");
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `day` property on [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) to calculate a date a certain number of dates from the current date:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.day = 30; // 30 days from launch

NSDate *expDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:today options:0];
```

This check should only be done the first time the app opens.  `expDate` should be persisted.  Every time the app launches fresh after the first time, do a date comparison from that first date.

```
// compare the dates
if ([today compare:expDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // trial expired
}
```